# What's the difference between "silicone sealant" and "MS-polymer" sealant?

Tags: silicone, sealant, chemicals

MS polymer (MSP) looks like silicone. It also comes in a tube, looks the same when it's liquid. Here are the differences I found with silicone caulk:

- it looks a bit less flexible when cured (looks like hard rubbery plastic).
- it's more expensive (3x) but it doesn't dry at all like silicone (I sealed it with the provided cap, and used it several (very hot) weeks later without any problem).
- It's much more pleasant to use:
- it's odorless (no solvent, it cures with [water from the] air)
- it doesn't stick on fingers like silicone (wiping the finger with tissue is enough to get rid of it).
- it takes much more time to cure (depending of the quantity you use; you can easily work with it during 10-30 minutes: for several cm3 I was wondering if it'll ever cure).
- I have seen on [this video](https://youtu.be/Mgyin-yh7UA?t=202) that unlike silicone, MSP has a non-staining property: it doesn't contain "oil", which could trap some dust and dirty its support.

But what are the other differences? Do both contain silicone? For what would you use one, but not the other?

(Chemistry based answers are also welcomed: I hesitated to post it in the stack chemistry)

Comment: It would help to know the context of what application/function you are planning to use this material for.   And possibly what delivery mechanisms / containers of product you are scoping out.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I updated my question concerning the delivery mechanisms (comes in a tube like silicone caulk). Concerning the application, it depend of the answer of my question! (My question is global, I'm just curious to know what could be done with it). For what I saw, It fills holes perfectly, feels like a hard rubbery plastic (seems harder than silicone caulk). It might be possible to mold stuff with it.

Comment: I would caution against using the word "mastic" to describe a particular product; in my part of the world "mastic" is a generic term for any "adhesive" but commonly used when referencing adhesives applied with a notched trowel.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it thanks for your feedback, I deleted it (it was confusing and not necessary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some information about it:

**What is it exactly?**

Look at this [YT video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uhHdER7XkWI) (though missing in my opinion 2 great advantages: 1) much easier to work with than silicon (doesn't stick and dry too quickly [edit*]), 2) huge lifespan once opened (it's hard to keep silicon for long time) ).

> MS Polymer™ is a water- and solvent-free, clear, odorless solution
> and liquid at room temperature. It has low volatility and a low Tg.
> When it comes into contact with a catalyst and water, a crosslinked
> matrix is formed, providing good heat and chemical resistance.
>
> MS Polymer stands for “modified silicone”, although it is not entirely
> silicone-based. It has a polyether backbone with reactive silyl
> functionality (telechelic).There are 2 kinds: a dimethoxysilyl (DMS)
> with 2 reactive groups (each side) on it and a trimethoxysilyl (TMS)
> with 3 reactive groups on it, making it a faster curing system than
> the DMS type. The TMS polymer is a newer version which creates a more
> strongly crosslinked matrix during curing in order to make harder and
> stronger material.
>
> The biggest difference with products common in the PSA and tapes world
> is that crosslinking occurs through moisture-curing. So by addition of
> a catalyst and subsequent contact with water, MS Polymer™ will start
> crosslinking and form a matrix structure. Besides the functionality,
> which can be altered by using either DMS or more reactive TMS, the
> polyether backbone can also be tuned by varying molecular-weight and
> branching. The polymer is telechelic, having 2 ends, but also a
> single-end version can be used as a kind of plasticizer. The product
> range includes a high-strength grade, meaning that the functional
> groups are even denser, creating even harder or higher-strength
> material. A mixture of polymers can be used to make many different
> kinds of products.

**What can you do with it?**

This add another advantage to the list above:

> - It's an adhesive.
>
> MS Polymer™ is mainly utilized in the adhesives and sealants world
> where it is a more common technology. (In contrast, silicone is not
> actually an adhesive, its adhesive qualities tend to break down much
> sooner than those of an actual adhesive [*](https://www.hotmelt.com/blogs/blog/silicone-sealant-handbook).) Its applications
> include sealants and adhesives for construction, automotive and DIY,
> such as waterproofing, glazing and insulating.
>
> The polymer is also fairly to very compatible with many rubbers,
> acrylics, resins and additives. In other words, it is very compatible
> with many components currently used in PSAs to make a tape.

**Polyurethane Sealant vs Silicone Sealant vs Polymer Sealant** (According to [sbdir.com](https://www.sbdir.com.au/polyurethane-silicone-vs-polymer-choose-polymer/)):

- **Highly durable** – harder than silicone, capable of withstanding high external forces and extreme climatic conditions. Expands and contracts as it’s exposed to the weather. Forms a seal preventing water and air escaping a system. Polymer solutions are typically good for a 5 year warranty.
- **Easily Customisable** – choose from extensive natural state colour range. Or, simply paint over with your choice of paint, including water-based paints.
- **Safe** – no isocyanate, does not irritate skin or cause occupational health issues and it is also environmentally friendly.
  Aesthetically Appealing – cures smooth, does not bubble or attract dirt.
- **Superior Cohesion** – adheres to many different substrates, more resistant against expansion/contraction.
- **UV Resistant** – Polymer can have various blockers, absorbers and stabilisers added to improve UV resistance. This makes it ideal for long-term use outdoors and in sunny environments.

- **Heat resistance**. I tested it with a heat gun till 400C no visible degradation nor fumes. (Seems great to protect electronic, like Kapton tape)

**Unanswered question:**

- Does it stick with itself as strongly as other material (I must test this).

**Others:**

- Don't buy MS polymer that doesn't have an expiration date. I bought several: they cured too quickly (5 min), and 1/3 of the tube had already cured

[source](https://www.afera.com/technical-centre/technical-and-product-research/ms-polymer%E2%84%A2-based-psa-technology.html)

Answer (score 0):

The "MS" stands for "Modified Silicone" (although some people think it should be "mostly silicone"), so yes, they both contain silicone.

A "polymer" just means a substance that has a molecular level bond with something else. So "MS Polymer" mastic is silicone sealant that is made with additional materials that change its properties. That's why it has different properties.

As to why they charge 2x more, the answer is the same as it is for anything;

"Because they can..."